# ExecuteInfluxDbQuery Processor throwing Null Pointer Exeption in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, influxdb, influxql

I am trying to retrieve data from my influx database using the following query :

```
select * from signal
```

But as soon as I run the processor I get the "**Null Pointer Exception**. Here's what my processor looks like :

[image]

I have tried retrieving data from both "**ExecuteInfluxDatabaseQuery**" and "**ExecuteInfluxDbQuery**" processor. Both are giving the Null pointer Exception. My infux version is 1.7.9.

Following is the ExecuteInfluxDb settings:

[image]

How can I successfully retrieve data from the InfluxDb? Thanks in advance

here is the stack trace :

```
2020-03-02 19:18:51,919 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-30] o.a.n.p.influxdb.ExecuteInfluxDBQuery ExecuteInfluxDBQuery[id=0170127f-cdc1-1b49-fd8b-f8e45de6a362] ExecuteInfluxDBQuery[id=0170127f-cdc1-1b49-fd8b-f8e45de6a362] failed to process session due to java.lang.NullPointerException; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

 at org.apache.nifi.processors.influxdb.ExecuteInfluxDBQuery.onTrigger(ExecuteInfluxDBQuery.java:182)

 at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)

 at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)

 at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)

 at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)

 at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2020-03-02 19:18:51,919 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-30] o.a.n.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask Administratively Yielding ExecuteInfluxDBQuery[id=0170127f-cdc1-1b49-fd8b-f8e45de6a362] due to uncaught Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

 at org.apache.nifi.processors.influxdb.ExecuteInfluxDBQuery.onTrigger(ExecuteInfluxDBQuery.java:182)

 at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)

 at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)

 at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)

 at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)

 at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2020-03-02 19:18:52,665 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-1] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@76951619 // Another save pending = false

2020-03-02 19:18:52,920 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-25] o.a.n.p.influxdb.ExecuteInfluxDBQuery ExecuteInfluxDBQuery[id=0170127f-cdc1-1b49-fd8b-f8e45de6a362] ExecuteInfluxDBQuery[id=0170127f-cdc1-1b49-fd8b-f8e45de6a362] failed to process session due to java.lang.NullPointerException; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: can you add log from nifi-app.log ?

Comment: @maximeG I have edited the original question with the stack trace!